# jQuery calls inside an generated div

Tags: jquery, forms, button, html, innerhtml

I'm trying to capture events from buttons that are generated into a div (feeded by another jQuery call). I wonder where the jQuery calls should be? Into the main page or into the generated html from the previous jQuery call?

Also, how jQuery deals with objects that have the same names?

Thanks!

Comment: You'll need to post the code you're using in order to get some help with this.

Comment: Well, the code is in separate pages, I just wonder where I should put the ready function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are working with objects that exits now or in the future, you have to use the live function to attach your events:

http://api.jquery.com/live/

*Description: Attach an event handler for all elements which match the current selector, now and in the future.*

If you have multiple objects that match the selector you will get an array of objects

Answer (score 0):

Create an example using [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/). It's hard to tell what your problem is at the moment.

To answer your first question you can register your events in both "main page" and "generated html", depends on the task. And since there's no code/example I can't tell which one is better for you.

Question "how jQuery deals with objects that have the same names?" doesn't really make sense. JQuery is a JavaScript library and JavaScript as any other programming language has a unique name for each object. Perhaps you meant element class names, jQuery treats them as a collection of elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can put it inside the generated html, if you're going to bind the event to that content that doesn't exist yet.

Like so :

```
$("#generatedButton").on("click",function(){
    //do something..
});
```

---

**OR**

You can put it in the main page, and bind the event to a higher wrapper that already exist and  specify the event target separately

Like so :

```
$("#mainWrapper").on("click", "#generatedButton" , function(){
    //do something..
});
```

---

All of that using [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).